# App Expose/Application Window Default Shortcut Across Different Versions

Tags: snow-leopard, macos

So I would like to know the default keyboard shortcut for Application Widow/App Expose from OSX from 10.6 - 10.12.

I have read it has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[So 10.6 uses the f10 key by default.](http://switchtoamac.com/guides/images/expose_leopard_system_preferences_01.png)

[10.7 and later use the control + down arrow.](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25703?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US#apd9036bca3eff14)

Comment: F3... it's printed on the key.

Comment: @Tetsujin I believe F3 is just regular expose and not app expose.  Also for which Operating System 10.6 or 10.7?  I'm fairly certain 10.7 is correct although I don't have the Operating System in front of me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they gave up with "Exposé" a while ago, now all you have is "Mission Control", on F3 by default [I don't have anything older than El Cap I can check on... & there's no way I'm going to hit 'Restore Defaults' to find out]

Comment: @Tetsujin hmm you may be right.  Do you mind going to this screen and seeing if this option does anything http://cdn.iphonehacks.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/mission-control-settings-el-capitan.png I see options like this on google and it makes me think it isn't gone http://www.tweaking4all.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/macosx-mission-control-open.jpg  maybe they have renamed it to mission control.  What does f4 do then?

Comment: This is [regular expose](http://www4.pcmag.com/media/images/211911-apple-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard-expose-from-dock.jpg) and this is [app expose](https://basshead.files.wordpress.com/2009/06/dock-expose.jpg) in 10.6 at least

Comment: Yeah, sorry... doesn't exist any more, can't test. 1st link, option is still there, never tried it tbh. 2nd link, idk what the pic is telling me. https://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/un-group-mission-control-windows-for-quicker-window-switching has something on i.